# Page slider with JavaScript - can't get slide to return to index 0 when reaches end

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm in the process of learning JavaScript and have started building a prototype portfolio page.

I have a main content element in the middle of the index page, where I want to slide through several div element pages which will hold content.

I'm able to get my JS slider to advance to the next div, however, when it reaches the end, I can't seem to get it to go back to the initial div element.
Also not having much luck getting the previous slide function to work properly. Any help would be most appreciated.

```js
const c1 = document.querySelector('.content-1');
const c2 = document.querySelector('.content-2');
const c3 = document.querySelector('.content-3');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');


const pages = [c1, c2, c3]
let i = 0;

const nextPage = function() {
 if(i < pages.length - 1) {
   i++;
   pages[i].classList.add('active')
 }
}

const prevPage = function() {
  if(i < pages.length - 1) {
    i--
    console.log(i)
    pages[i].classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    pages[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
}

next.addEventListener('click', nextPage)
prev.addEventListener('click', prevPage)
```

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1.8fr 1fr 1.8fr 0.2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.8fr 2.5fr 1fr 0.5fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav nav nav"
    ". . . . ."
    ". main main main ."
    ". . . . ."
    "footer footer footer footer footer";
}

.nav { grid-area: nav; }

.footer { grid-area: footer; }

.main { 
  grid-area: main; 
  overflow: hidden;
}


html, body , .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
  
/* For presentation only, no need to copy the code below */

.container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.container *:after {
  content:attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
/*   z-index: 3; */
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
/*   z-index: 2; */
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-3 {
  position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
/*   z-index: 1; */
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 4;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.pages {
  opacity: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/09/20/23/12/earth-6642058_1280.png" class="background">

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="nav"></div>
  
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content-1 pages active">Content 1</div>
    <div class="content-2 pages">Content 2</div>
    <div class="content-3 pages">Content 3</div>
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
 
</div>
  
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your prevPage function should look like this:

```js
const prevPage = function() {
  if(i > 0) {
    pages[i].classList.remove('active');
    i--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the code and got it to work.
Thank you @userharis for replying to my initial post!

```
const pages = document.querySelector('.page-container').children;
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
let totalPages = pages.length;
let index = 0;

const updatePagePosition = function () {
  for (let page of pages) {
    page.classList.remove('active');
    // page.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  pages[index].classList.add('active');
};

const nextPage = function () {
  if (index === totalPages - 1) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index++;
  }
  updatePagePosition();
};

const prevPage = function () {
  if (index === 0) {
    index = totalPages - 1;
  } else {
    index--;
  }
  updatePagePosition();
};

next.addEventListener('click', nextPage);
prev.addEventListener('click', prevPage);
```